# Adding multidiemnsionall array to <input type=checkbox>

Tags: html, multidimensional-array

Ok,

I have my form something like this
(html format)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="opt[]" value="php echo $option['optionname']?>
```

I'm processing above option[] as array and currently it has only optionname.

Now I want to add 'optionprice' as well.As every option users select has a price.

So it should come something like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="opt[][]" value="php echo $option['optionname'] $option['optionprice'] >
```

Comment: @user Shouldn't PHP tags go like so: `<?php [code here] ?>`

Comment: Not going to work. Your app can't know where to split the value. You need to do something with javascript if you want it like this. Better would be a redesign with for example hidden input fields with the prices.

Comment: You know you can use key names in HTML input names - like `name="opt[identifier][price]"`, where identifier could be the array index.

Answer (score 0):

Not certain I fully understand your question. The input element has one name and one value. You could allow multi-dimensional data to be entered, and parse it out on the server. But you should consider the user experience of that UI design.

If you are looking for a way to embed meta data, take a look at jQuery data. It allows you to embed data into the element's markup and easily retrieve it. Here is a link

http://api.jquery.com/data/

Hope this helps.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

Given that I understand your question correctly: if you know the price already for each option, you don't need to submit it via the form. You can just match the selected option with the price on your backend.

Otherwise, one way to send multi-dimensional arrays through POST would be:

```
<!-- product A with 2 prices --> 
<input type="checkbox" name="opt[productA][]" value="<?php echo $option['productA']['price1']; >
<input type="checkbox" name="opt[productA][]" value="<?php echo $option['productA']['price2']; >

<!-- product B with 3 prices --> 
<input type="checkbox" name="opt[productB][]" value="<?php echo $option['productB']['price1']; >
<input type="checkbox" name="opt[productB][]" value="<?php echo $option['productB']['price2']; >
<input type="checkbox" name="opt[productB][]" value="<?php echo $option['productB']['price3']; >
```